# Faraday cages - Size of holes

Tags: waves, electric-fields, frequency

I wanted to learn more about Faraday cages and one thing that caught my attention is the relationship between the wave frequency and the hole in the cage. Why is that the higher the frequency of the wave the smaller the holes it can penetrate? The frequency is supposed to correlate the number waves and time so how does this all fit together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of any holes need to be significantly smaller than the wavelength of light you want to block.

If you go to high enough frequencies then the wavelength becomes small enough for the waves to diffract through your cage.

If you look at [What is the relationship between Faraday cage mesh size and attenuation of cell phone reception signals?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/149607/what-is-the-relationship-between-faraday-cage-mesh-size-and-attenuation-of-cell) you will see that, for a rectangular mesh, the critical thing is that the mesh width should be smaller than $\lambda/2$. Below this, the signal amplitude will be attenuated exponentially, on a length of $\sim \lambda/2\pi$, so ideally your mesh would be thicker than this.

Comment: would covering the holes with aluminum foil solve the problem?

Comment: Yes. Aluminium is highly reflective and also attenuates any electromagnetic radiation that penetrates the surface. @Trey

Comment: is there a way to calculate the size of the hole based on the frequency of the wave?

Comment: $\lambda = c/f$ ? @Trey

Comment: I know how to calculate the frequency/wave length, what I want to know is: given the frequency say 500Mhz how can I find the smallest hole which is able to shield such a signal. You said "holes need to be significantly smaller than the wavelength" but how much smaller?

Comment: Microwave door screen holes are about a milliliter or roughly a tenth of the wavelength of about 120 mm and they effectively block microwaves

Comment: The optimum hole size depends on the compromise you seek between screening effect and accessibility through the holes. The thickness and electrical and magnetic properties of the material you make the holes through are also significant. Aluminum foil is a cost-effective screen but it is not a high-quality one. It gets complicated. As a rule of thumb, a hole size of less than one-tenth of the wavelength is a good starting point.

Comment: @Trey you haven't said by what factor you want to attenuate the signal. The two are of course directly related.

Comment: @RobJeffries now I get it, just one more thing. Say I don't have any holes in my cage, then can I be sure that no matter how the high the frequency gets, it won't get in(or out)?

Comment: @Trey No. You need to calculate what fraction is reflected and then what fraction of signal transmitted through the surface is attenuated before it gets through.

Answer (score 2):

microwave ovens work at a wavelength of about 10 cm. If you measure the hole diameters in the screen that sits in front of the window in the door of the oven, you'll have your answer.

Comment: The holes in microwave doors are made so small as much for visibility as anything. Bigger holed would mean bigger areas of metal in between, which would obscure the food inside.